# XMLHttpRequest status 0 on second load

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I am experiencing an interesting issue when I am trying to load some data in .txt format from the same domain using XMLHttpRequest.
I am trying to load the data, parse it and then store it in localStorage

```
var xmlhttp;
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

var temp;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        temp = xmlhttp.responseText;

    }else{
        alert("readyState: " + xmlhttp.readyState + "status: " + xmlhttp.status);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","data/somedata.txt", false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

This code only works if I clean the history and cache; however, on second click of the same link, I would received "Readystate: 4, status 0" for some reason.

Does this has anything to do with localStorage?

```
if (!localStorage.somedata || localStorage.somedata.count(':') !== somedata.count(':')) {
  localStorage.somedata = temp;
}
window.somedata = JSON.parse(localStorage.somedata);
```

Comment: I assume the browser caches the file, so you get the "200 OK" status only the first time. Repeated requests should result in "304 Not Modified". I'm not sure why you get 0...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Perhaps if no request was made at all, and the page was just served from the cache?

Comment: @lonesomeday Yea, I guess that's it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two causes of status code of zero.

1. Making calls from the file protocol.
2. The page is refreshing/navigating away as the request is being made.

In your case I would assume it is #2. If you are using a button or a link to make the Ajax call, make sure to cancel the click action with either `preventDefault` or `return false`.

Comment: While your answer probably has the most valuable information to this question, I believe your assumption is wrong. There is spoken of an refresh but not during any requests.

Comment: @epascarello it's not a button though. It's called every time the app is loaded. I tried to put in  a function and return; if there is no internet connection. However, that doesn't solve the problem either.
There is javascript is running on ruby on a local server. Does that have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: How does the code get called? If there is no button/link making the page refresh, is there some other event changing the page?

Comment: @epascarello This code is called directly every time the page is loaded, since the .txt file is being updated all the time.
 I feel this code is influenced by other part of .erb file.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a caching issue.  Try either switching to a `POST` method, or appending a timestamp to the `GET` request querystring and see if that prevents the caching.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "data/somedata.txt", false);
```

or:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "data/somedata.txt?" + new Date().valueOf(), false);
```

**Edit:** If those don't work, modify your server configuration to send appropriate response headers for that file or type to not cache the response.  Ie: `Cache-Control: no-cache`

Comment: I tried POST before. I got status = 404...
I just tried to add the timestamp to GET, still got status 0

Comment: You may have to modify your server settings to send back headers for that file or filetype not to cache.

Comment: @user959974 Check the Network tab in Chrome's dev tools. Is a HTTP request made every time?

Comment: Status zero has nothing to do with caching.

Comment: @epascarello How do you know?

Comment: @Šime Vidas  status is 304 instead of 0 somehow, and responseText is still showing up although the status is 304.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I tried using safari instead, I have status 200 for first attempt and then "Pending" for the second try.
Is there request send?

Comment: @user959974 (1) The response text shows up on status 304, and it should! "Not Modified" means that the content is retrieved from the browser's cache. (2) Eventually it should change from "Pending" to something else. Did you close the alert box and then looked?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas 1)The same code would show 304 in chrome and 200 in safari though 2) it would be pending there with: "XMLHttpRequest Exception 101: A network error occured in synchronous requests."

Comment: @user959974 (1) Both status codes are acceptable. The important thing is that you get your response text. (2) Is it necessary that your request is synchronous? Try an asynchronous request.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas  I wanted to load completely first before run the rest.. I guess I can put everything else inside.
It works on safari on mac but not the on safari on ipod...
What is the key difference between asynchronous request and synchronous request...

Comment: @user959974 A synchronous AJAX request will block the UI (the web-site basically) until the response has been received. I don't know why one would want to do that. If you don't know which one to use, use the asynchronous one. To do that, define the third argument of `open()` as `true` instead of `false`.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? cancel your click and see if the status 0 error magically goes away.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I put the same code on a apache server, the xhr would run fine, but when i run it on the ruby based server it would produce the status 0 response. Would that be the issue instead?
If so, how can I make it work on ruby?

Comment: @user959974 What code? JavaScript runs in the browser, not on  server.

Answer (score 0):

Try `xmlhttp.abort()` before opening a new request.

It's a long shot but worth the try.

Comment: You can have multiple requests open at the same time, abort will do nothing here.

Comment: That would depend on the scope and context where its being used. Given the information above there is no way to tell. Therefor it would be a long shot.