# XMLHttpRequest with status 0

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, ajax-request

I'm trying to use XMLHttpRequest, but when I call xmlhttp.send(post), I received xmlhttp with state 1 and status 0. I think that state equals 1 is ok, because mean server connection established, but why status 0? Unfortunately, the other side doesn't receive my request.

```
function ajaxRequest(method, url, post, callback_fn){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { //code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { //code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open(method,url,true);
    if (method=="POST"){
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", post.length);
    }
    xmlhttp.send(post);
    console.log("xmlhttp.readyState = " + xmlhttp.readyState); // = 1
    console.log("xmlhttp.status = " + xmlhttp.status); // = 0
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You have to actually wait until the readyState is 4, and then check the status. Look at examples online.

Comment: Okay I deleted my orginal question, How do you call this method? Button click, form submission?

Comment: I call this method with button click (onclick).

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest status 0 on second load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576064/xmlhttprequest-status-0-on-second-load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancel the click and see if it stops the status zero.

```
onclick="ajaxRequest(...); return false;"
```

Problem is page is refreshing and killing the Ajax request.

Comment: All right @epascarello, when I put return false in **onclick**, **onreadystatechange** function is fired. Why I need to do that? Is it the right way?

Answer (score 2):

The `onreadystatechange` event fires when the state changes, and only when there's a return response can you check what the statusCode of the request was (200, 404 etc.)

```
function ajaxRequest(method, url, post, callback_fn){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { //code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { //code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            console.log("xmlhttp.status = " + xmlhttp.status);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open(method,url,true);
    if (method=="POST"){
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", post.length);
    }
    xmlhttp.send(post);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already tried it, but my application never call onreadystatechange function. What could be the problem?

Comment: It's not something your application calls, all XMLHttpRequests will fire the onreadystatechange event multiple times when doing an ajax request -> http://jsfiddle.net/776Wg/

Comment: Yes, I know that. I'll express myself better. My XMLHttpRequest doesn't fire onreadystatechange, ever, and doesn't show any javascript exception or error log.

Comment: That would suggest that the `ajaxRequest` function is never called.

Comment: No, I call that. I can confirm this because I see the ` console.log("xmlhttp.readyState = " + xmlhttp.readyState); // = 1
console.log("xmlhttp.status = " + xmlhttp.status); // = 0`, called into ajaxRequest function.